# conteo de transaciones agrupados SQL

Tags: sql

intento hacer un conteo de intentos realizados en cada comercio con una tarjeta diferente, es decir la tarjeta 123456 realizo 5 intento en amazon.com y el último fue aprobado(QUINTO intento) , no quiero tomar en cuenta los casos que nunca se aprobaron, ejemplo se hizo 3 intentos con las tarjeta 896321 pero ninguno no tuvo aprobación todas fueron denegadas, ese tipo de caso quiero excluirlos del reporte

ESTA ES LA DATA Y CAMPOS DE LA TABLA TRANSACCIONES

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ESTE ES REPORTE QUE QUIERO GENERAR DE LA DATA DE LA TABLA ANTERIOR , LAS TRANSACCIONES DE DE AMAZON NO SE TOMAN EN CUENTA DEBIDO QUE NO HUBO AL FINAL UNA APROBACION.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
with data as (
        SELECT 
              TARJETA
               , COMERCIO
                , CAST(TRANSACCIONES.FECHA_HORA_TRANSACCION AS DATETIME) as fecha
             ,TRANSACCIONES.ESTADO
         , month(CAST(TRANSACCIONES.FECHA_HORA_TRANSACCION AS DATETIME)) as mes
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                   (   
                    PARTITION BY TARJETA, COMERCIO,MONTO,
                              month(CAST(TRANSACCIONES.FECHA_HORA_TRANSACCION AS DATETIME))
                         ORDER BY TARJETA, COMERCIO
                               , CAST(TRANSACCIONES.FECHA_HORA_TRANSACCION AS DATETIME)
                 ) As rn
               FROM TRANSACCIONES
), par as (
       Select TARJETA, 
             COMERCIO,
             mes, 
           min(fecha) mnFecha, 
            min(rn) mnFila, 
         max(fecha) mxFecha,
         max(rn) mxFila
      from data
      
        group by TARJETA, COMERCIO, mes
)
select TARJETA,
              COMERCIO,
              
               mxfila as intentos,
         Cast((datediff(hour,mnFecha, mxFecha)*1.0/24) as decimal(4,2)) as dias
         
from par
```

Comment: Hola Carlos, para que podamos ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y si recibes errores, indica cuales son. Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo esta solución en MySQL:

```
SELECT tarjeta,comercio,codigo_comercio,monto,
  COUNT(*) intentos,
  DATEDIFF(MAX(t.fecha_hora_transaccion),MIN(t.fecha_hora_transaccion)) dias
  FROM transacciones t JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM transacciones
      WHERE estado='APROBADA'
  ) c1 USING(tarjeta,comercio,codigo_comercio,monto)
  GROUP BY 1,2,3,4;
```

El dataset con los datos que propones:

```
CREATE TABLE transacciones(
  id_transaccion int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  tarjeta int,
  comercio varchar(31),
  codigo_comercio int,
  monto float,
  fecha_hora_transaccion datetime,
  estado varchar(15)
  );
INSERT INTO transacciones (tarjeta, comercio, codigo_comercio, monto, fecha_hora_transaccion, estado) VALUES
  (123456,'netflix.com',78945,9.99,'2020-12-12 8:10:15','DENEGADA'),
  (123456,'netflix.com',78945,9.99,'2020-12-13 8:10:15','DENEGADA'),
  (123456,'netflix.com',78945,9.99,'2020-12-13 8:30:15','DENEGADA'),
  (123456,'netflix.com',78945,9.99,'2020-12-13 9:10:15','DENEGADA'),
  (123456,'netflix.com',78945,9.99,'2020-12-14 8:10:15','APROBADA'),
  (321456,'disneyplus',89654,7.99,'2020-12-12 8:10:15','DENEGADA'),
  (321456,'disneyplus',89654,7.99,'2020-12-12 9:10:15','APROBADA'),
  (896321,'amazon.com',789614,10.99,'2020-12-13 9:10:15','DENEGADA'),
  (896321,'amazon.com',789614,10.99,'2020-12-14 9:10:15','DENEGADA'),
  (896321,'amazon.com',789614,10.99,'2020-12-14 9:20:15','DENEGADA');
```

Y el resultado que esperas:

```
+---------+-------------+-----------------+-------+----------+------+
| tarjeta | comercio    | codigo_comercio | monto | intentos | dias |
+---------+-------------+-----------------+-------+----------+------+
|  123456 | netflix.com |           78945 |  9.99 |        5 |    2 |
|  321456 | disneyplus  |           89654 |  7.99 |        2 |    0 |
+---------+-------------+-----------------+-------+----------+------+
```

Espero que te resulte útil. La parte que me ha parecido más complicadilla es la de seleccionar aquellas transacciones que finalmente quedan aprobadas que resuelvo quedándome con las que tienen estado APROBADA y combinando por el resto de campos. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.